# finding image format

Tags: images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a tool that can determine the file type from containing data?](https://superuser.com/questions/274734/is-there-a-tool-that-can-determine-the-file-type-from-containing-data)

How do I find out the format of a picture on windows 7? If i right click on the picture and check the properties, it just gives me the dimensions, but not the picture format.
Is there any tool to find that out?

Comment: If the file extension isn't enough to tell you, then use the method in  [Is there a tool that can determine the file type from containing data](http://superuser.com/q/274734/20088). Usually the extension (`.jpg`, `.png`, etc.) should be enough though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageMagick's `identify` can recognize may image formats, and even present some details about the file.