# How can I detect if the extension of a file has been modified?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, file-extension

For example I have `picture1.JPG` then another user of my computer change the extension from `picture1.JPG` to `picture1.PNG`, I am sure that in most cases it will work. My question is this, is there a way to detect if a files extension has been modified?

Comment: Practically outside windows, file extensions matter little.

Comment: duplicate question here https://superuser.com/questions/274734/is-there-a-tool-that-can-determine-the-file-type-from-containing-data?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

The [`file`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/file.1.html) program examines the contents of files, showing their actual type (with occasional misses).  If you are using a Unix-like system, you probably already have it installed (there is a [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/file.html) description of it, for instance).  For Windows, there is a port in [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) (a little old, but better than nothing).

The program lists each filename, along with the types.  All you have to do (with a script would be nice) is to look for mismatches between the two (filename versus description of its type).

Here is some sample output to illustrate:

```
escher03.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.02
snakes.jpg:   JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
sphere.gif:   GIF image data, version 87a, 1120 x 832
spirals.jpg:  JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.00, comment: "U-Lead Systems, Inc."
square_l.gif: GIF image data, version 87a, 634 x 668
st_peter.gif: GIF image data, version 87a, 640 x 480
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to give you another alternative if you need to work only with images. You can use the command `identify`, which belongs to ImageMagick:

```
$ identify stellarium-000.png
stellarium-000.png PNG 1364x728 1364x728+0+0 8-bit sRGB 248KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```